# How to show/hide when hover in/out on specific element

Tags: javascript, css

I make a secondary menu and I like it to be displayed when user hover a specific one of the main menu items....

I tried this code but it didn't work...

```css
.second-menu {display:none}
ul li #2:hover + .second-menu {display:block}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="1">first</li>
  <li id="2">second</li>
  <li id="3">third</li>
<ul>
  
  <div class="second-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>page1</li>
      <li>page2</li>
      <li>page3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

any suggestions?....
only by css or javascript....

Comment: You have to use javascript for this. css not work, because your .scond-menu div is outside of ul > li markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use CSS, you will have to put your sub menu inside the element that you want to hover.

For the CSS, C.Raf.T's answer is perfect.

If for some reason you want to use javascript you could do something like this

```
document.getElementById('2').addEventListener('mouseenter', function ()
{
  document.getElementById('subMenu').style.display = "block";
});
document.getElementById('2').addEventListener('mouseleave', function ()
{
  document.getElementById('subMenu').style.display = "none";
});
```

Note: the above code requires you to add a "subMenu" id to the div containing your menu. If you wish to display serval menus with only one hover event, use a class instead.

But honestly, the CSS answer is the best way to go if all you need is nested sub menus.
If the sub menu has to be outside of the parent, you will need the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.second-menu{
  display:none;
}
li:hover >.second-menu{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="1">first</li>
  <li id="2">second  
 
    <ul class="second-menu">
      <li>page1</li>
      <li>page2</li>
      <li>page3</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  <li id="3">third</li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: The reason way I cant use this structure is that I need both the main and the secondary menu to be 100% width, and as you know, when the secondary menu is inside another element, it cant be in full width because he's limited to the width of his parent element...
unless there's a trick I don't know about...

Answer (score 0):

By using pure CSS you have to ensure that your submenu (`.second-menu`) is a child-node of your hovered HTML-Element. Because CSS unfortunately doesn't know a parent selector.

By using JS you are more flexible. Means placing the submenu wherever you wish.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.second-menu {display:none; border: 1px solid blue; width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; }
ul li#two:hover > .second-menu {display:block}
.relative { position: relative; border: 1px solid black; }
li { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<ul class="relative">
  <li id="one">first</li>
  <li id="two">second
    <ul class="second-menu">
      <li>page1</li>
      <li>page2</li>
      <li>page3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="three">third</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: The reason way I cant use this structure is that I need both the main and the secondary menu to be 100% width, and as you know, when the secondary menu is inside another element, it cant be in full width because he's limited to the width of his parent element...
unless there's a trick I don't know about...

http://rakowerliran.com/extreme-toys/
this is the website I'm doing, and the item that opens is "Shop".... and i need it to look like the secondary menu.... full width....

Comment: A combination of `position: absolute` and `position: relative` may fit your needs. See the adapted example code.

Comment: you're right, it's exactly what I need! but for some reason it doesn't work on my website :(

Comment: Probably a problem with your websites' CSS. Inspect with Web Developer Tools, look especially at positioning etc...

Comment: Seems like your second menu isn't child of first element. : (

Answer (score 0):

Answer using Javascript,

```js
document.getElementById('hover').onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementById('second-menu').style.display = 'block';
}

document.getElementById('hover').onmouseout = function(){
    document.getElementById('second-menu').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.second-menu{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="hover">
  <li id="1">first</li>
  <li id="2">second</li>
  <li id="3">third</li>
<ul>
  
  <div class="second-menu" id="second-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>page1</li>
      <li>page2</li>
      <li>page3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchtkvv5/)

Comment: Sravan: this not what I meant, I need the secondary menu to be displayed when hover on only one of the items of the main menu....